How can i implement Show more show less functionality using html widget in flutter?
I have used flutter_quill package for getting the description, now I want to show the description with read more read less functionality and looking for any html parser which can do this.thanks
Although if I parse the text like
String htmlString =''' <p> hello<br/>newline</p> ''';

using flutter html package 

parse(htmlString).body!.text

output : hellonewline

Expected Output: hello 
                 newline

